# Disable window reaction to ShowWindow function call

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a WPF window with disabled resize capability (WindowStyle=None, ResizeMode = CanMinimize).

It works fine, except one situation. If some application (i.e AutoHotKey) calls a WIN API function  ShowWindow on my window with SW_MAXIMIZE option, then my window repositions to (0, 0) coordinate on the desktop with no size change and user is not able to move it over the screen further.

How can I disable this behavior? I want the window to ignore this call on my window.

I have tried reacting to WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING event, but this works only until user minimizes the window. After it is minimized and restored it becomes repositioned to (0, 0) coordinate again.

```
private IntPtr ProcessMessage(IntPtr windowHandle, int msg, IntPtr wideParam, IntPtr leftParam, ref bool handled)
{
    Msg windowsMessage = (Msg)msg;
    switch (windowsMessage)
    {
        case Msg.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
            {
                WindowPos windowPos = (WindowPos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(leftParam, typeof(WindowPos));

                if (IsNoClientAction(windowPos) && !IsMinimizing(windowPos) && window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
                {
                    windowPos.Flags = SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE;
                    handled = true;
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(windowPos, leftParam, true);
                }

                break;
            }
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private static bool IsNoClientAction(WindowPos windowPos)
{
    return (windowPos.Flags & SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOCLIENTSIZE) != 0 || (windowPos.Flags & SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOCLIENTMOVE) != 0;
}

private static bool IsMinimizing(WindowPos windowPos)
{
    return windowPos.Left == -32000 && windowPos.Top == -32000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have analyzed what `user32.dll` does to the window and figured out solution based on that. Before sending any messages to `Wndproc` it updates `GWL_STYLE` flags of the window enabling `WS_MAXIMIZE` for it. For this reason window state becomes corrupted and further behavior can hardly be handled by processing window messages only.

To disable window reaction on `ShowWindow` with `SW_MAXIMIZE` option I am setting this flag back when `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` is processed:

```
private IntPtr ProcessMessage(IntPtr windowHandle, int msg, IntPtr wideParam, IntPtr leftParam, ref bool handled)
{
    Msg windowsMessage = (Msg)msg;
    switch (windowsMessage)
    {
        case Msg.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
            {
                WindowPos windowPos = (WindowPos)Marshal.PtrToStructure(leftParam, typeof(WindowPos));

                if (IsNoClientAction(windowPos))
                {
                    WindowStyles styles = (WindowStyles)WindowsAPI.GetWindowLongPtr(windowHandle, GWL.GWL_STYLE);
                    if ((styles & WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZE) != 0)
                    {
                        windowPos.Flags |= SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOMOVE;
                        WindowsAPI.SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(this, windowHandle), GWL.GWL_STYLE, (IntPtr)(long)(styles ^ WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZE));
                        handled = true;
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(windowPos, leftParam, true);
                    }
                }

                break;
            }
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}

private static bool IsNoClientAction(WindowPos windowPos)
{
    return (windowPos.Flags & SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOCLIENTSIZE) != 0 || (windowPos.Flags & SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOCLIENTMOVE) != 0;
}
```